# Apt full-upgrade not updating all packages

Tags: apt, kubuntu

Any thoughts on what could cause the below?

```
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/19.04/prod disco InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:3 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x eoan InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                      
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease                
Hit:8 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:9 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/serge-rider/dbeaver-ce/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:11 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports InRelease
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

~$ sudo apt full-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libodbc1/disco 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.6-0.1build1]
odbcinst1debian2/disco 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.6-0.1build1]
odbcinst/disco 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.6-0.1build1]
```

I found someone else with a similar question on this website, but it never got properly answered/explained.

Answer (score -2):

### *** UPDATE APPENDED ***

Try running this:

*sudo apt install libodbc1 odbcinst1debian2 odbcinst -y*

That just installs those three apps that are upgradable, calkling them out one by one, typing them manually... and the -y at the end just answers yes to any question that pops up.. so you dont have to answer manually.

good luck

-Booey

## Update:

Sorry. I mis-read your question. Allow me to *try* and correct my mistake.

I myself have ran into this same issue a while back. From what I remember, the issue happens because the option "full-upgrade" is different from the "dist-upgrade" option.

Now, its been a while, but I believe that those items are showing up when you run update because you have "pre-released updates" selected in your Software Properties App.

I dont have anything that is upgradable so I can't test this out, but i think it you run apt / apt-get with dist-upgrade, thosew items will upgrade, and you can see that the two options are different

sorry for the crappy answer.. its been a while since i looked this up

### UPDATE #2:

I just looked up my answer, and I can say that I am confident in what I said.

If you open Software Properties App and check the "Developer Options" tab, you should see that the "pre-released updates" is checked.

Just unselect it if you don't want to deal with this issue again.

Cheers

-Booey

Comment: but it doesn't explain _why_ this is happening...

Comment: sorry.. updated my answer

Comment: It's 2023, but in 2022.10 at least, this is happening even with pre-released unchecked. I run full-upgrade and there are almost always a slew of upgrades I have to manually upgrade for some reason that I can't figure out